# Cannot connect to wifi via command line

Tags: command-line, networking, network-manager

I am simply trying to connect to my WPA2 network using the command line. I have tried what seems like everything for the past few hours, but no success.

**Attempt #1**

So I have tried to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file with the following information:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
       wpa-ssid "my ssid with spaces"
       wpa-psk "my cleartext password"
```

Tried to bring the interface down with `ifconfig down` and `ifup -v wlan0`, only to be presented with this error:

```
ifup: configuring interface wlan0=wlan0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ifenslave
+ [ inet = meta ]
+ IF_BOND_SLAVES=
+ [  ]
+ [  ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ exit
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/macchanger
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -C /run/wpa_supplicant
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
ifup: failed to bring up wlan0
```

**Attempt #2**

Next, I tried to use wpa_supplicant instead.

```
# wpa_passphrase "my ssid with spaces" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
<my cleartext password followed by Enter>
```

I tried to start wpa_supplicant using the following command: `wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dnl80211` only to be presented with the following output:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlan0: No network configuration found for the current AP
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=e8:fc:af:fa:e1:69 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
^Cnl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

**Attempt #3**

I have also tried to just use `iwconfig` from the command line, but that doesn't ever work either:

```
# iwconfig wlan0 essid "my ssid with spaces" key "cleartext password"
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    invalid argument "cleartext password".
```

**Attempt #4**

Not sure what I did differently, but now `wpa_supplicant` seems to associates to my AP and then disassociates. I have verified that the password is correct as well. Here's the output of running it without specifying a driver in command line arguments:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with e8:fc:af:fa:e1:69 (SSID='my ssid with spaces' freq=5240 MHz)
wlan0: Trying to associate with e8:fc:af:fa:e1:69 (SSID='ssid with spaces' freq=5240 MHz)
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with e8:fc:af:fa:e1:69 (SSID='ssid with spaces' freq=5240 MHz)
wlan0: Trying to associate with e8:fc:af:fa:e1:69 (SSID='ssid with spaces' freq=5240 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with e8:fc:af:fa:e1:69
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=e8:fc:af:fa:e1:69 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
^Cnl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

**Attempt #5**

Now I'm trying to use `wpa_cli` and it seems like it's associating, bu disassociating again. I see that auth_failure = 1 but this can't be right because I just literally pasted the password on my laptop and connected just fine, pasted it into the CLI and it failed.

```
<3>Trying to associate with e8:fc:af:fa:e1:69 (SSID='my ssid with spaces' freq=5240 MHz)
<3>Associated with e8:fc:af:fa:e1:69
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
<3>CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=e8:fc:af:fa:e1:69 reason=3 locally_generated=1
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="my ssid with spaces" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
<3>CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems like just simply getting connect to Wi-Fi via command line is proving to be extremely difficult. I am using a Gigabyte Mini-PC.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I always configure it using `wpa_cli` as explained [here in the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_cli), that’s simple and works exactly like that for Ubuntu as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @dessert. Haven't used this command before but I'm also getting an error when using that. Going to update the original post.

Comment: Are you sure your router is set to allow new connections?

Comment: yep I do. is that a bad thing?